# Assert that every string in a set has an associated key in an object

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

After reading through the Open Policy Agent introduction documentation a few times, I'm having trouble writing a rule which asserts that for every element in a set, the specified object has an associated key.

Here's a simplified example what I'm currently trying to get working

https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/oWBumjRkWX

```
package example

my_object = {
  "lemon": ""
}

fruits = {
  "orange",
  "lemon",
  "banana"
}

has_key(x, k) { _ = x[k] }

default has_lemon = false
has_lemon = has_key(my_object, "lemon") # this works as you'd expect

default all_fruits_have_entries_in_my_object = false
all_fruits_have_entries_in_my_object { # this is never false for some reason
  some fruit
  fruits[fruit]
  has_key(my_object, fruit) # each fruit have a key in the my_object object
}
```

From what I understand, `has_lemon` should be false when the `fruits` does not contain the `"lemon"` element and I've tested that this is working. However, I also thought that the `all_fruits_have_entries_in_my_object` rule should evaluate to `false` here since `my_object` is missing keys for `"orange"` and `"banana"`. Am I doing something stupid here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rego is existentially quantified. That means rules are declared to check if there exists *some* fruit that is a key of the object.

One way to solve the problem: you can first gather all unexpected keys using a comprehension and then count the result:

```
package example

my_object = {
  "lemon": ""
}

fruits = {
  "orange",
  "lemon",
  "banana"
}

has_key(x, k) { _ = x[k] }

default has_lemon = false
has_lemon = has_key(my_object, "lemon") # this works as you'd expect

default all_fruits_have_entries_in_my_object = false
all_fruits_have_entries_in_my_object { # this is never false for some reason
  non_fruit_keys := { key | my_object[key]; !fruits[key] }
  count(non_fruit_keys) > 0
}
```

You can evaluate this example in the [Rego Playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/yp2aT7RYrG).

See also the documentation on [Universal Quantification in Rego](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#universal-quantification-for-all)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that documentation. I got it to work using

`default some_fruits_dont_have_entries_in_my_object = false
some_fruits_dont_have_entries_in_my_object {
  some fruit
  fruits[fruit]
  not has_key(my_object, fruit)
}
not some_fruits_dont_have_entries_in_my_object # this does what I need`